# Spring Profiles in connection String

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, spring-mvc

I am working with **Spring Boot** & **Docker**. I am using a `connectionService.java` which returns the **connection** to perform some task. This connection string has `jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false`. If I am running the application than it is running well but If I build the docker image than this connection string should be replaced with `jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql/databaseName?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false`. Because docker-image has config with **docker-mysql** not **localhost**  .

**ConnectionService.java**

```
@Service
public class ConnectionService {
    public Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "root");
        return connection;
    }
}
```

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3'

services:
  docker-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=databaseName
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 3307:3306

  app:
    image: app:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - docker-mysql
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql/databaseName?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root
```

> Error: At the minute. I'm facing the error **Communication Link failure**.
>   How I could do this that the same code works for Running application & also when the docker image is build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL environment variable in Docker-compose, but do not use this at your ConnectionService.

Perhaps, you can use System.getEnv() or @Value annotation from Spring.

Modify your ConnectionService class:

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String datasourceUrl;

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(datasourceUrl, "root", "root");
```

Comment: Updated my asnwer.

Comment: this will work for the **docker-image**  but how I could use the same code for "running application" too?

Comment: You can set this in your application.yml/properties
So, when you run in your local machine, the value will be read from your config file, when you run in docker, the environment variable overrides it.