# How dockerize Spring Boot app if Postgres db is going to be AWS RDS?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api_service:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
    links:
      - postgres_db:database
  postgres_db:
    image: "postgres:11.4"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5435:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: testDb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
```

this is my YAML file.

and I got properties

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/testDb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
```

if my Postgres is `rds` then do I need to compose them or I just can go with Dockerfile for `jar` only and not YAML file?

Comment: Welcome @engineering_the_future, although not what you asked, you may want to investigate AWS secrets capability and store you RDS credentials there.  Then you'd only have to specify the secret name and leverage the AWS apis to get the credentials.  https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/

Comment: yes I was gonna do it with aws secret manager thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create environment variables for the RDS address, RDS username, RDS password and RDS port. Pass it to the Dockerfile to the api_service. Your api_service should know to assemble Postgres connection string based on the environment variables. Please check - [Spring Profiles in connection String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59194194/spring-profiles-in-connection-string)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/16359258/syscloud so depends_on (yml file) for app and db is gonna be needed anyway right??

Answer (score 0):

Those Spring properties values are probably incorrect in most of the environments in which you might run your application.  In your unit-test environment the database might be H2 or HDBC instead of PostgreSQL; in a local-developer setup it will be on `localhost`; in RDS it will be a different name again.  These host names and credentials should not be in your `src/main/resources` tree anywhere.

Spring allows you to [set Spring properties using environment variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables).  So you can set *e.g.* `spring.datasource.url` at the point where you deploy your application.  In your Compose setup, for example:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  api_service:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres_db:5432/testDb
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=admin
  postgres_db:
    image: "postgres:11.4"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5435:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: testDb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
```

If your production environment uses RDS, then it should be enough to remove the `postgres_db` container and change the `SPRING_DATASOURCE_*` environment variables to match the RDS host name and credentials.  You don't have to recompile anything or change the contents of your jar file.